# powershell exception has misleading InvocationInfo

Tags: powershell

given the script.

```
$foo = @("bar")

try {
    $foo | ForEach-Object {
        Join-Path $null $null
    }
} catch {
    $_.InvocationInfo.Line
}
```

will print

```
$foo | ForEach-Object {
```

but I would like

```
Join-Path $null $null
```

How can I get where the exception was actually raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will get you the actual line:

```
$_.Exception.CommandInvocation.Line
```

and exception message:

```
$_.Exception.Message
```

and line number:

```
$_.Exception.Line
```

and offset (column):

```
$_.Exception.Offset
```

So you could make a helpful little message:

```
} catch {
    $msg = "Failed to do something. Failed on line number '{0}' column '{1}' ('{2}'). The error was '{3}'." -f 
        $_.Exception.Line, $_.Exception.Offset, $_.Exception.CommandInvocation.Line.Trim(), $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Error $msg
}
```